# Centos 7 сломал yum

Tags: centos7

полетели ошибки segmentation fault на python, переустановить/удалить не получалось, сделал `rpm -e python --nodeps` (роковая ошибка, уже понял...) и теперь yum мне говорит `/usr/bin/yum: /usr/bin/python: bad interpreter: No such file or directory`

руками python не могу поставить, т.к. при попытке поставить зависимости, они зацикливаются одна требует другую О_о в частности python(abi) который ведёт на главный пакет питона, а пакет питона без него не ставится, т.к. нужны python-libs, которым нужен python(abi) вот такой порочный круг. как-то можно восстановить работоспособность yum или уже проще переустановить систему?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

в общем скопировал файл /usr/bin/python2.7 с аналогичного сервера, накинул права 755 и всё завелось

Comment: увы, мне не помогло. Может потому что абсолютно идентичного сервера не было(

Comment: ага, помогло, после того как переименовал python2.7 to python